# matrix design for d3.js' chords

Tags: javascript, d3.js, chord, chord-diagram

I found [here](http://blog.kathyreid.id.au/2016/09/01/valentines-day-a-data-visualization-to-learn-chords-in-d3js/) an d3.js chord example. Unfortunately, I do not understand how could I change his below [matrix](https://github.com/KathyReid/valentines-dataviz/blob/master/js/dataviz.js#L8) to my data.

```
var matrix = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], // Bob
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], // Giovanni
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], // Steve
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], // Kevin
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], // Art
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], // Pyotr
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], // Rohan
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], // Rachel
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], // Sasha
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], // Emily
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], // Lee
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], // Viva
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]  // Poh
]
```

My data is separated in 2 json files. The first one describe the circle labeling, color and size

```
[
  {
    "color": "#996600", 
    "id": "chr03", 
    "len": 35020413, 
    "label": "chr03"
  }, 
  {
    "color": "#666600", 
    "id": "tig00007144", 
    "len": 40868, 
    "label": "tig00007144"
  }, 
  {
    "color": "#666600", 
    "id": "tig00026480", 
    "len": 95961, 
    "label": "tig00026480"
  },
...
]
```

On the other hand, the second file describes the relationship between each label in the chord chart.

```
[
  {
    "source": {
      "start": 30824, 
      "end": 23113, 
      "id": "tig00007144"
    }, 
    "target": {
      "start": 33203431, 
      "end": 33211142, 
      "id": "chr03"
    }
  }, 
  {
    "source": {
      "start": 48387, 
      "end": 1, 
      "id": "tig00026480"
    }, 
    "target": {
      "start": 35010628, 
      "end": 34962190, 
      "id": "chr03"
    }
  }, 
...
]
```

How do I convert the above relationship file to a proper matrix?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'll need to create your own square matrix - similar to: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1046712

Comment: Would you be able to show me how the actual matrix for my data need to look like?

Comment: Second object: source.id= rows, target.id= columns, each instance should count as 1 for the corresponding cell?

Comment: I still don't understand how to create the matrix. Could you please show me maybe without any coding how would the matrix look like from the above 2 JSON files?